# PHP socket client not returning full response

Tags: php, python, sockets, client, response

I have a Python socket server and a PHP socket client. The client sends a command to the server and then displays the response on the page. It works perfectly almost all the time. Now the issue I have is that when it comes to long responses, the response seems to cut of.

It's not the Python server as you get the complete response via Telnet. It's something with the PHP script that I can't for the life of me, figure out.

**Output from Telnet:**

```
{  
   "status":1,
   "ramPerc":25,
   "console":"[12:49:18 INFO]: --------- Help: Index ---------------------------\n[12:49:18 INFO]: Use /help [n] to get page n of help.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: Aliases: Lists command aliases\n[12:49:18 INFO]: Bukkit: All commands for Bukkit\n[12:49:18 INFO]: Minecraft: All commands for Minecraft\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /achievement: Gives the specified player an achievement or changes a statistic value. Use '*' to give all achievements.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /ban: Prevents the specified player from using this server\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /ban-ip: Prevents the specified IP address from using this server\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /banlist: View all players banned from this server\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /clear: Clears the player's inventory. Can specify item and data filters too.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /defaultgamemode: Set the default gamemode\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /deop: Takes the specified player's operator status\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /difficulty: Sets the game difficulty\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /effect: Adds/Removes effects on players\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /enchant: Adds enchantments to the item the player is currently holding. Specify 0 for the level to remove an enchantment. Specify force to ignore normal enchantment restrictions\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /gamemode: Changes the player to a specific game mode\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /gamerule: Sets a server's game rules\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /give: Gives the specified player a certain amount of items\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /help: Shows the help menu\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /kick: Removes the specified player from the server\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /kill: Commits suicide, only usable as a player\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /list: Lists all online players\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /me: Performs the specified action in chat\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:achievement: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:ban: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:ban-ip: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:banlist: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:clear: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:defaultgamemode: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:deop: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:difficulty: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:effect: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:enchant: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:gamemode: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:gamerule: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:give: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:help: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:kick: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:kill: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:list: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:me: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:op: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:pardon: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:pardon-ip: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:playsound: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:say: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:scoreboard: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:seed: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:setidletimeout: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:setworldspawn: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:spawnpoint: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:spreadplayers: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:tell: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:testfor: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:time: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:toggledownfall: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:tp: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:weather: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:whitelist: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /minecraft:xp: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /netstat: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /op: Gives the specified player operator status\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /pardon: Allows the specified player to use this server\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /pardon-ip: Allows the specified IP address to use this server\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /playsound: Plays a sound to a given player\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /plugins: Gets a list of plugins running on the server\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /reload: Reloads the server configuration and plugins\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /restart: Restarts the server\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /save-all: Saves the server to disk\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /save-off: Disables server autosaving\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /save-on: Enables server autosaving\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /say: Broadcasts the given message as the sender\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /scoreboard: Scoreboard control\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /seed: Shows the world seed\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /setblock: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /setidletimeout: Sets the server's idle timeout\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /setworldspawn: Sets a worlds's spawn point. If no coordinates are specified, the player's coordinates will be used.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /spawnpoint: Sets a player's spawn point\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /spreadplayers: Spreads players around a point\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /stop: Stops the server with optional reason\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /summon: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /tell: Sends a private message to the given player\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /tellraw: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /testfor: Tests whether a specifed player is online\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /testforblock: A Mojang provided command.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /time: Changes the time on each world\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /timings: Manages Spigot Timings data to see performance of the server.\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /toggledownfall: Toggles rain on/off on a given world\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /tp: Teleports the given player (or yourself) to another player or coordinates\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /tps: Gets the current ticks per second for the server\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /version: Gets the version of this server including any plugins in use\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /weather: Changes the weather\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /whitelist: Manages the list of players allowed to use this server\n[12:49:18 INFO]: /xp: Gives: the specified player a certain amount of experience. Specify <amount>L to give levels instead, with a negative amount resulting in taking levels.\n",
   "ram":517,
   "players":[  

   ],
   "ramMax":2048,
   "cpu":1
}
```

**And output from PHP script:**

```
{
   "status": 1, 
   "ramPerc": 16, 
   "console": "[12:57:42 INFO]: --------- Help: Index ---------------------------\n[12:57:42 INFO]: Use /help [n] to get page n of help.\n[12:57:42 INFO]: Aliases: Lists command aliases\n[12:57:42 INFO]: Bukkit: All commands for Bukkit\n[12:57:42 INFO]: Minecraft: All commands for Minecraft\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /achievement: Gives the specified player an achievement or changes a statistic value. Use '*' to give all achievements.\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /ban: Prevents the specified player from using this server\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /ban-ip: Prevents the specified IP address from using this server\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /banlist: View all players banned from this server\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /clear: Clears the player's inventory. Can specify item and data filters too.\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /defaultgamemode: Set the default gamemode\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /deop: Takes the specified player's operator status\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /difficulty: Sets the game difficulty\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /effect: Adds/Removes effects on players\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /enchant: Adds enchantments to the item the player is currently holding. Specify 0 for the level to remove an enchantment. Specify force to ignore normal enchantment restrictions\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /gamemode: Changes the player to a specific game mode\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /gamerule: Sets a server's game rules\n[12:57:42 INFO]: /give: Gives the specified player a certain amount of items\n[12:57:42 INFO]:
```

I've searched around for a few weeks and tried everything, but can't figure out the issue.

**Here's the PHP script behind all this:**

```
public function send($cmd, $host, $port, $timeout = 1.5){
    // Get time of function start
    $startTime = time();

    //Try to create a socket
    if(!($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)))
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        //If failed, die with error. (Check docs)
        die("Error (#300)");
    }

    if(!socket_set_nonblock($socket)){
        die("Error (#301)");
    }

    while(!@socket_connect($socket, $host, $port)){
        if ((time() - $startTime) >= $timeout){
            die("Error (#302)");
        }
        continue;
    }

    if(!socket_set_block($socket)){
        die("Error (#303)");
    }

    if(!socket_write($socket, $cmd, strlen($cmd)))
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        die("Error (#304)");
    }
    $reply = socket_read($socket, 16384)
            or die("Error (#305)");

    socket_close($socket);
    return $reply;
}
```

If anyone knows how to solve this issue, please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should test the return value of [`socket_write()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-write.php) whether it did send as much data as it was told to send, that is `strlen($cmd)` bytes. If this isn't the case write the rest to the socket until all data was send out.

From the [`socket_write()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-write.php)'s documentation:

> **socket_write()** does not necessarily write all bytes from the given buffer. It's valid that, depending on the network buffers etc., only a certain amount of data, even one byte, is written though your buffer is greater. You have to watch out so you don't unintentionally forget to transmit the rest of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It seems like it does send as much data as it was told to.


`cmd bytes: 44 | bytes written: 44`

It's weird, as everything works without issues, except when we're dealing with a big string

Comment: Hmm ... the input you show is definitly large then 44bytes. @RsMusicRs

Comment: What I put in the question was the output, not the input :)
The input isn't long at all. This is the command being sent to the server: `4159a4030602995553945d2e2b807d46console help`. @alk

Comment: Ahok, I somehow had an echo-server in mind. However I suspect the `socket_read()` function behaves similar. From `socket_read()`'s [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php): "*Reads a maximum of length bytes from a socket*" Mind the "*maximum*". @RsMusicRs

Comment: I've tried to increase it, but no luck. The output from telnet is only `6516 bytes` which is not even close to 16k. @alk

Comment: Do I simply duplicate the current `$reply = socket_read($socket, 16384) die("Error (#305)");`, and put it right under it? Sorry, but I've never had to call socket_read twice. I've tried to duplicate it, but the script hangs. @alk

Comment: Better go for `socket_recv()`.

Comment: Also I wonder why you set the socket to non-blocking before connecting and afterwards back to blocking. Just remove those two calls.

Comment: Just duplicating the call would make you lose what already had been receive by the first call.

Comment: Need to set to non-blocking and blocking after connecting for socket_read to work if the connection didn't time out. Also, I can't seem to get anything out of socket_recv(). Returns null.

Comment: I did manage to get the reply, but it still cuts. Will investigate further. @alk